# facing problems with grid for single row

Tags: css, css-grid

```css
.layout {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: 1fr 11fr;
     grid-auto-rows: minmax(100vh, auto);
}
 .layout_menu {
     height: 90vh;
     grid-row: 0.3333333333;
}
 .layout_menu-menu {
     display: flex;
     writing-mode: vertical-rl;
     overflow: auto;
     max-height: 75vh;
     align-items: flex-start;
}
 .layout_menu-menu-link {
     padding: 2rem 0rem;
     font-size: large;
}
 .layout_menu-menu-link a {
     color: #dff0e5;
     text-decoration: none;
}
 .layout_menu-menu-link a:hover {
     color: #696969;
}
 .layout_menu-logo {
     width: 5rem;
     height: 5rem;
     margin: 1rem 0rem;
}
 .cont {
     border: greenyellow 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="layout_menu">
    <img class="layout_menu-logo" src="assets/H_logo.png" alt="H Logo" />
    <div class="layout_menu-menu">
      <div class="layout_menu-menu-link"><a href="/p1">page1</a></div>
      <div class="layout_menu-menu-link"><a href="/p2">page2</a></div>
      <div class="layout_menu-menu-link"><a href="/p3">page3</a></div>
      <div class="layout_menu-menu-link"><a href="/p4">page4</a></div>
      <div class="layout_menu-menu-link"><a href="/p5">page5</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="layout_main cont">
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to use the grid to arrange the layout on my page.

below is my CSS and HTML code.

```
.layout{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 11fr;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(100vh, auto);
    &_menu{
        height: 90vh;
        grid-row: 1/3;
        @include for-size(phone-only){   
            display: flex;
            margin-left: 0rem;
        }
        &-menu{
            display: flex;
            writing-mode: vertical-rl;
            overflow: auto;
            max-height: 75vh;
            align-items: flex-start;
            &-link{
                padding: 2rem 0rem;
                font-size: large;
                @include for-size(phone-only){
                    padding: 0.2rem;
                    font-size: large;
                }
                a{
                    color: #DFF0E5;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    &:hover{
                        color: #696969;
                    }
                }
            }

            @include for-size(phone-only){   
            writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
            }
        }
        &-logo{
            width: 5rem;
            height: 5rem;
            margin: 1rem 0rem;
            @include for-size(phone-only){
                margin:  0rem;
            }
        }
    }
}

.cont{
    border: greenyellow 1px solid;
}
```

```
<div class="layout">
    <div class="layout_menu">
        <img class="layout_menu-logo" src="assets/H_logo.png" alt="H Logo"/>
        <div class="layout_menu-menu">
            <div class="layout_menu-menu-link"><a href="/p1">page1</a></div>
            <div class="layout_menu-menu-link"><a href="/p2">page2</a></div>
            <div class="layout_menu-menu-link"><a href="/p3">page3</a></div>
            <div class="layout_menu-menu-link"><a href="/p4">page4</a></div>
            <div class="layout_menu-menu-link"><a href="/p5">page5</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="layout_main cont">
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't understand why is total screen height so much higher than 100vh even when I don't have content.

I want the page to end just with the green border. Can anyone help me understand the cause of this?

[SS after scrolling halfway to the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccj6o.png)

Comment: Hi it would be really helpful if you could turn your code into a working snippet - see [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have added it  in snippet but somehow it is working fine in code snippet but not in my local